# is there a way to make discord.py copy a certaint part of the text sent by users

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Is there any way for discord.py bot to copy a certain part of the message, for example:

The user sends `print('hello')` in the chat, the bot responds with the text in the brackets, in this case `hello`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [regex](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/re.html)

```py
import re
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot()

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    content = message.content # in this case: print('hello')
     
    # any character inside of '' (0 or more)
    result = re.search(r'\'[^"]*\'', content).group(0)

    # remove ' around string
    result = result.strip("'")

    await message.channel.send(result)
```

Result

```
hello
```

Comment: is there a way to maek it compatabel whit "" and variables(if a user types for example "g = 10g" and then print(g) it would print 10g)